# Find Regex mismatch part in a string using vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I had a regex expression

```
^\d{9}_[a-zA-Z]{1}_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_\d*_[0-9a-zA-Z]*_[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

and string that match regex expression

```
000066874_A_12.31.2014_001_2Q_ICAN14
```

if user by mistake enters the string other than above format like

```
000066874_12.31.14_001_2Q_ICAN14
```

**I need to find out in which part of my regex got failed.** I tried using Regex.Matches and Regex.Match but using this I couldn't find in which part my string got miss matched with my Regex expression. I am using vb.net

Comment: I don't think regex is particulary suited for this. It's probably possible, i.e. writing every part with lookarounds and capturing them. Hence, the group that got failed will be empty or not returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is very complicated to do with regex. I managed to make this regex, but you still have to check the capture groups after that.

`^(?:(?:(\d{9})|.*?)_)?(?:(?:([a-zA-Z]{1})|.*?)_)?(?:(?:((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4})|.*?)_)?(?:(?:(\d*)|.*?)_)?(?:(?:([0-9a-zA-Z]*)|.*?)_)?(?:([0-9a-zA-Z]*)|.*?)$` will work if you, as seen in demo: https://regex101.com/r/aJ1wG1/2

Each part before an underline is a capture group, if a capture group is not there, there's an error in it. As you can see in the example, $3 is not present in 1st example, hence, a mistake in date is there. In second example, the $2 is not present, hence $2 onward are not there. 3rd example is correct and all 6 caputre groups are there.

When regexes get this massive, it's a sign that probably a different method should be used to solve the problem, but this might work for you with some additional code for group result checks.